# Merge [trial], [time-bomb] and [time-trial] with [trialware]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Could we merge the following tags under [trialware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trialware)

[trialware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trialware) (40) existing wiki
[time-bomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-bomb) (4)  no wiki
[time-trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-trial) (21) no wiki
[trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trial) (129)  no wiki

Some of them are OT so a manual review would be necessary in any case.